# How to get input of multiple char and longint separated by a space in single read()?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I tried this but it give me Runtime error 106.

```
var
  a, c: char;
  b, d: longint;
begin
  read(a, b, c, d);
  write(a, ' ', b, ' ', c, ' ', d);
end.
```

The input is

```
A 1 B 2
```

Comment: Read the string, and parse it

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, okay i will try it.

Comment: You need a function that splits strings on spaces. A websearch will reveal many such functions.

Comment: The other comments indicate the correct approach. But the specific reason you get the error has to do with where the "input pointer" is when you read. The read of `a` reads up to the first space, then read of `b` reads ` 1` (space and 1) as a `1` for `b`, reading up to the second space. The read of `c` reads that space into `c` as a character. Then `read` attempts to read the `B` into long integer `d` which fails with runtime error 106 (invalid numeric format).

Comment: @David: I guess he could use a `TStringList` to split the input string, if there is no `Split()`-like function. AFAIK, FreePascal has stringlists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DavidHeffernan commented, and as @lurker explained, your code won't work as-is.

Assuming you have a *FreePascal* version that knows the `TStringList` type in unit `Classes` (I guess all recent ones do), you can do the following:

```
uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

procedure Test;
var
  a, c: Char;
  b, d: Longint;
  s: string;
  sl: TStringList;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Writeln('Enter a char, a number, a char and a number again, separated by spaces:');
    // Read entire line
    Readln(s);

    // Split s into four entries in the string list
    sl.Delimiter := ' ';
    sl.DelimitedText := s;
    if sl.Count >= 4 then
    begin
      a := sl[0][1];         // first string item, convert to char
      b := StrToInt(sl[1]);  // second string item, convert to integer
      c := sl[2][1];         // third string item, convert to char
      d := StrToInt(sl[3]);  // fourth string item, convert to integer
    end;
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
  Writeln(a, ' ', b, ' ', c, ' ', d);
end;

begin
  Test;
end.
```

You should probably add error checking for the case you get bad input, and perhaps use `TryStrToInt` instead of `StrToInt`, but I'll leave that as an exercise.

As @lurker said, in your question, you are trying to read Chars, which causes problems, because for instance a space and a tab are also a Chars, so the space delimiters don't work as you expected here. This will mess up the entire input. The only way to get these items is to read the entire string and then to parse it (split it).

If your version of FreePascal has a unit `StrUtils` with a `SplitString` function in it, you can use that instead of a `TStringList`. It splits the string, using a given delimiter (here `' '`) into a dynamic array. That is perhaps a little simpler, but not much.

Comment: I am using Free Pascal Compiler version 3.0.0, when try to run your code it raise some error at `try` and `finally` line. Because i just start learn using pascal i don't know how to fix it so i removed those lines and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Add  {$mode delpihi} to the top to put the compiler in delphi mode or compile with -Sd

Comment: @Marco: doesn't plain FreePascal have try-finally, or does it work differently?

Comment: Freepascal's dialect is TP-like dialect. Note that lazarus projects are initialized with an Object Pascal (but not Delphi) like dialect by default

Comment: Try-finally are part of most Object Pascal implementations, AFAIK. I wonder why it needs Delphi mode to compile.

Answer (score -1):

I try this and worked but it need more unused variable.

```
var
  a, c: char;
  b, d: char;
  e, f, g, h: char; // take care of space
  p, q: char;
  x, y: longint;
begin
  read(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h);
  p := a;
  q := e;
  x := ord(c) - 48;
  y := ord(g) - 48;
  write(p, ' ', x + 1, ' ', q, ' ', y + 1);
end.
```

Comment: You can try to use a lot of variables and then perhaps hit the right number, so some of them are filled with meaningful content, but that is not programming. You should know what to expect. Do not use Char to read space, since if someone enters `A 107  B  2`, possibly with a few extra spaces, then you are out of luck. Don't do that. "It works with this input" is never a good excuse to do things the wrong way.

Comment: I really wonder who upvoted this answer. Adding variables until it matches one single input is not proper programming.

Comment: You can force this to work with the extra variables, but it's a very poor approach as it makes the code quite fragile. Various slight changes in input format can cause the code to fail again.